# How to use RSpec from the IRB console?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I would like to try all the nice oneliners in the documentation of RSpec in the IRB console.

How to execute them in the IRB console?

Please a solution not based in Rails, just plain Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be just what you're looking for:

> Standalone
>   require "rspec/mocks/standalone" to expose the API at the top level (e.g. main) outside
>   the RSpec environment in a REPL like IRB or in a one-off script.

See https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/outside-rspec/standalone